# How to get a RESX string by passing culture, not using thread culture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, cultureinfo, resx

I have several strings in a range of RESX files for 5 cultures/languages. I have an MVC view where different parts of the view will need to display different languages (it is an invoice print roll which contains multiple invoices, each of which will be in one of 5 languages).

Is there any way for me to get RESX strings by key with the ability to define the culture explicitly rather than relying on the thread culture?

I cannot use the thread because my single view will need to display multiple languages at different points.

I want to do something like this:

```
@MyRESX.String1("de-DE") 

@MyRESX.String1("fr-FR")
```

I can code this up manually using HTML helpers and had coding the strings (I only have about 20 strings), but that feels nasty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have now figured this out via a Helper method.

1) Add your RESX files and set them to have 'public' access modifier

2) Create a helper function which looks something like this where 'MyNamepsace.ResourceClass' is the full path to the class beneath your default RESX file. You can find this by looking at the *.Designer.cs file beneath your RESX

```
public static class Lang
{        
    public static string GetGlobalString(string key, string language)
    {
        CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(language);
        ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(typeof(MyNamespace.ResourceClass)));
        return rm.GetString(key, ci);
    }
}
```

3) In my MVC view, I can now do something like this:

```
@Lang.GetGlobalString("String1", "de-DE")
```

or

```
@Lang.GetGlobalString("String1", "en-GB")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string GetImplementedCulture(string name)
    {
        // make sure it's not null
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            return GetDefaultCulture(); // return Default culture

        // make sure it is a valid culture first
        if (_validCultures.Where(c => c.Equals(name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Count() == 0)
            return GetDefaultCulture(); // return Default culture if it is invalid


        // if it is implemented, accept it
        if (_cultures.Where(c => c.Equals(name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Count() > 0)
            return name; // accept it



        // Find a close match. For example, if you have "en-US" defined and the user requests "en-GB", 
        // the function will return closes match that is "en-US" because at least the language is the same (ie English)  
        var n = GetNeutralCulture(name);
        foreach (var c in _cultures)
            if (c.StartsWith(n))
                return c;



        // else 
        // It is not implemented
        return GetDefaultCulture(); // return Default culture as no match found
    }
```

This is a nice code i have found, Im using it in my projects all the time, you just add a List of Languages or Cultures you support like this:

```
   private static readonly List<string> _validCultures = new List<string> { "af", "af-ZA", "sq", "sq-AL", "gsw-FR", "am-ET", "ar", "ar-DZ", "ar-BH", "ar-EG", "ar-IQ", "ar-JO", "ar-KW", "ar-LB", "ar-LY", "ar-MA", "ar-OM", "ar-QA", "ar-SA", "ar-SY", "ar-TN", "ar-AE", "ar-YE", "hy", "hy-AM", "as-IN", "az", "az-Cyrl-AZ", "az-Latn-AZ", "ba-RU", "eu", "eu-ES", "be", "be-BY", "bn-BD", "bn-IN", "bs-Cyrl-BA", "bs-Latn-BA", "br-FR", "bg", "bg-BG", "ca", "ca-ES", "zh-HK", "zh-MO", "zh-CN", "zh-Hans", "zh-SG", "zh-TW", "zh-Hant", "co-FR", "hr", "hr-HR", "hr-BA", "cs", "cs-CZ", "da", "da-DK", "prs-AF", "div", "div-MV", "nl", "nl-BE", "nl-NL", "en", "en-AU", "en-BZ", "en-CA", "en-029", "en-IN", "en-IE", "en-JM", "en-MY", "en-NZ", "en-PH", "en-SG", "en-ZA", "en-TT", "en-GB", "en-US", "en-ZW", "et", "et-EE", "fo", "fo-FO", "fil-PH", "fi", "fi-FI", "fr", "fr-BE", "fr-CA", "fr-FR", "fr-LU", "fr-MC", "fr-CH", "fy-NL", "gl", "gl-ES", "ka", "ka-GE", "de", "de-AT", "de-DE", "de-LI", "de-LU", "de-CH", "el", "el-GR", "kl-GL", "gu", "gu-IN", "ha-Latn-NG", "he", "he-IL", "hi", "hi-IN", "hu", "hu-HU", "is", "is-IS", "ig-NG", "id", "id-ID", "iu-Latn-CA", "iu-Cans-CA", "ga-IE", "xh-ZA", "zu-ZA", "it", "it-IT", "it-CH", "ja", "ja-JP", "kn", "kn-IN", "kk", "kk-KZ", "km-KH", "qut-GT", "rw-RW", "sw", "sw-KE", "kok", "kok-IN", "ko", "ko-KR", "ky", "ky-KG", "lo-LA", "lv", "lv-LV", "lt", "lt-LT", "wee-DE", "lb-LU", "mk", "mk-MK", "ms", "ms-BN", "ms-MY", "ml-IN", "mt-MT", "mi-NZ", "arn-CL", "mr", "mr-IN", "moh-CA", "mn", "mn-MN", "mn-Mong-CN", "ne-NP", "no", "nb-NO", "nn-NO", "oc-FR", "or-IN", "ps-AF", "fa", "fa-IR", "pl", "pl-PL", "pt", "pt-BR", "pt-PT", "pa", "pa-IN", "quz-BO", "quz-EC", "quz-PE", "ro", "ro-RO", "rm-CH", "ru", "ru-RU", "smn-FI", "smj-NO", "smj-SE", "se-FI", "se-NO", "se-SE", "sms-FI", "sma-NO", "sma-SE", "sa", "sa-IN", "sr", "sr-Cyrl-BA", "sr-Cyrl-SP", "sr-Latn-BA", "sr-Latn-SP", "nso-ZA", "tn-ZA", "si-LK", "sk", "sk-SK", "sl", "sl-SI", "es", "es-AR", "es-BO", "es-CL", "es-CO", "es-CR", "es-DO", "es-EC", "es-SV", "es-GT", "es-HN", "es-MX", "es-NI", "es-PA", "es-PY", "es-PE", "es-PR", "es-ES", "es-US", "es-UY", "es-VE", "sv", "sv-FI", "sv-SE", "syr", "syr-SY", "tg-Cyrl-TJ", "tzm-Latn-DZ", "ta", "ta-IN", "tt", "tt-RU", "te", "te-IN", "th", "th-TH", "bo-CN", "tr", "tr-TR", "tk-TM", "ug-CN", "uk", "uk-UA", "wen-DE", "ur", "ur-PK", "uz", "uz-Cyrl-UZ", "uz-Latn-UZ", "vi", "vi-VN", "cy-GB", "wo-SN", "sah-RU", "ii-CN", "yo-NG" };
```

and use this to change your culture. if you need more details just ask.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, but I'm not quite seeing how this code addresses the problem? This code appears to return a culture, but I want to actually return a string from a RESX by passing in a culture.

Comment: @MartinKearn Why don't you write a custom class that accesses RESX, something like `public string GetTranslation(string key, string languageID){ return translation;}` ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this still does not answer the question - what would the code look like inside this method to access the correct RESX based on the languageID?

Comment: @MartinKearn Oh you figured it out, i just wanted to post my answer, anyway good luck!